# при авторизации сессии в своем API приложении и старте приложение закрываются вообще все активные сессии у меня на телефоне и компьютере

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

У меня есть небольшое свое приложение на python, которое мониторит определенные группы и пересылает в мою группу определенные сообщения
До поза вчерашнего дня все работало отлично.
Я не менял приложение и ни чего не менял.
НО!
Со вчера при авторизации сессии в своем API приложении и старте приложение
закрываются вообще все активные сессии у меня на телефоне и компьютере, хотя ни я и ни кто либо не завершал сеансы. И так же сам Апи не работает,
я получаю такую ошибку и приложение не работает:

"The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions"
(Перевод: Авторизация была признана недействительной, так как пользователь завершил все сеансы)

Spam info bot пишет, что нету ни каких ограничении
«Ваш аккаунт свободен от каких-либо ограничений.»

Можете уточнить, такая проблема только у меня?
Может это какое то заувалированное ограничение от телеграма? Или это какой то баг?
Пробовал запускать и на другом компьютере в другой сети. И даже другое приложение под другим аккаунтом. Тоже самое теперь получаю.
Так же с этим приложением работает аккаунт моего товарища, и у него нет таких проблем.
И я не могу понять, что не так.
Какие пути решения данной проблемы.
Спасибо большое. Очень жду вашего ответа и любую дополнительную информацию. Так как не понимаю что происходит.
Поиски в интернете не дают результаты. Поддержка телеграм не отвечает. Написал им на 4 разные почты)

Элементарный скрипт на котором валятся все сеансы на всех устройствах:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions
api_id = 1111111111
api_hash = 'fааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааf'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
status = await client(functions.account.GetAccountTTLRequest())
print(status)

client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Смена аккаунта и IP адреса не помогает. У Вас получилось решить проблему?

Comment: Поддержка телеграм выдаст бан за такое. Подобное использование противоречит ToS. Это из-за недавнего обновления телеграма. Из вариантов решения заюзать другую библиотеку или трастовые аккаунты, например, с премиумом

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать версию при создании клиента
TelegramClient(...., system_version='4.16.30-vxCUSTOM')

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, откуда значение `4.16.30-vxCUSTOM` и какие есть варианты?